# How find function works in unordered_map is searching for key value

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I was solving the question in leetcode.com. The question is 2sum. Link: [2sum question](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/)
The following was the best solution provided by someone:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class Solution{
public:
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &nums, int sum){
    //write code here
    int len = nums.size();
    unordered_map<int, int> hashTable;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        int diff = sum - nums[i];
        auto found = hashTable.find(diff);
        if(found == hashTable.end()){
            hashTable.insert(pair<int, int>{nums[i], i});
        }
        else{
            return vector<int>{found->second, i};
        }
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> myArray;
    vector<int> outputArray;
    int sum,n,temp;
    cout<<"enter the size of the array\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter the integers\n";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>temp;
        myArray.push_back(temp);
    }
    cout<<"enter the sum\n";
    cin>>sum;
    Solution s;
    outputArray = s.twoSum(myArray, sum);
    cout<<"["<<outputArray[0]<<","<<outputArray[1]<<"]"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `auto found = hashTable.find(diff);` how this line is working as the hashTable was never initialized. So, how it is finding the diff value. And then how the if condition is working?
When I tried to print the contents of the hashTable using iterator, it returned empty value i.e., hashTable was empty. Then how it is finding the diff value?
Please help me in understanding.
Thanks for all the opinions.

Comment: If a key with the value of `diff` is not found, it is inserted into the hash-table. So the table is *initially* empty, but not for long.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: *"it is inserted into the hash-table"* -- no it isn't. Are you thinking of `operator[]`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley `if(found == hashTable.end()){ hashTable.insert(pair<int, int>{nums[i], i}); }`. That's what that [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) call does. Okay, so it doesn't insert `diff`, but it does insert values into the table.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The `insert` call inserts something, but not `diff`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley What is inserted into the map is kind of irrelevant to the question actually. What is important is that *something* is inserted. The map will not stay empty which the OP seems to think.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Understood, but the wording of your original comment implied that it was the actual call to `find` that did the insertion. And I feel it was important to correct that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'll happily admit that. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you search for a key using `unordered_map::find`, and it is not found, the `end()` iterator is returned. Which is a non-dereferencable iterator, because it doesn't actually point to an element. You can see in the very next line that this is the condition that is being checked for:

```
if(found == hashTable.end()){
```

And in this branch, the `found` iterator is not dereferenced. So it's not a problem if the map is empty, because the code handles that case.